# How to get all files present from UNC path java?

Tags: java, unc, vfs, apache-commons-vfs

Am try to get all files present in UNC path using `apache commons-vfs2` library.

But am not find way to list files present in UNC path with valid credentials.And then do manipulations in all files.

I tried following code for access file present in UNC.

```
String domain="xxxxx";
String userName="xyz";
String password="aabbcc";
File f=new File("E:/destination");
String remoteFilePath="\\\\hostname\\foldername";
UserAuthenticator auth=new StaticUserAuthenticator(domain, userName, password);
FileSystemOptions opts=new FileSystemOptions();
DefaultFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserAuthenticator(opts, auth);
FileObject fo=VFS.getManager().resolveFile(remoteFilePath,opts);
FileObject destn=VFS.getManager().resolveFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
destn.copyFrom(fo,Selectors.SELECT_SELF);
destn.close();
```

Here i have given `filename append with remoteFilePath` it moves that file into my destination directory.

If i give only directory name in remoteFilePath it not worked.

**Now i need to get all files present in "UNC Path" without give filename.After reading those files then do some changes inside files to be moved into destination directory.**

Anyone suggest way to do it?

Comment: cifs in apache vfs is in sandbox state. If the remote device is mounted you don't need any library. I suppose you refactor to use `java.io.File.listFiles()` to find the files inside the directory. BTW: I'm missing some sort of loop in your code.

Comment: listFiles() not working when i access network drive with credentials.Tha'ts why am go to vfs

Comment: You need to specify the method name used to Retter the smb provider, like smb://server/share - and also use forward slashes as VFS works on URL syntax.